# What tag should be used for specific values in a generic message (e.g. "Do you want to delete <tag>ABC</tag>?")?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Let's say I have a generic message, such as

> Do you want to delete {object} from {environment}?

I want to emphasise non-generic parts (object/environment).
Currently I use `<em>`, but it is missing any semantics over *why* this is emphasised, so the emphasis becomes more stylistic than semantic.

Is there a better choice — some tag where this is defined as explicit use case?

Comment: Well, why do you want to emphasize it?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Because if user has seen this message before, he is unlikely to be interested in reading the generic text -- only the parts that change between messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [`b` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) is appropriate here.

It is for "text to which attention is being drawn", "without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood".

I don’t think the [`strong` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) is appropriate; it might be [for the whole warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522180/1591669), but not specifically for the name of the thing that gets deleted. And neither is the [`em` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element), as there is no emphasis involved.

In some cases, depending on the actual content, elements like `abbr`, `a` and `cite` might be used, too, but this would be *in addition*, not as alternative.

Comment: Thanks, this seems the best option based on the examples in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with the strong tag. The strong tag indicates strong importance for the enclosed text.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong

Comment: Hmm, based on that page it does seem a better choice than `<em>`, however the examples with "danger" etc seem overly strong for what I need. Seems like with `<strong>` I should emphasise "delete", not what I am deleting.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like it could be a little strong. For reference, here's the complete list of text-level semantics tags you can use, from the W3C reference: https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements#Text-level_semantics.